# Managing logarithmic Array data for use on a HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, arrays, normalization, logarithm

I have a data set in an array ranging from 0.00164737 to 0.0021966

> **What I am trying to do is get the shape fixed by logarithmic scale, then to normalize it ready for drawing on the canvas. Say normalized to *0,100* or *-100,0,100* so I can work in pixels**

To simply normalize (without doing a log function) between 0-100 this works lovely in a for loop:

```
normalized[i] = ( ( close[i] - min ) / dif ) * 100;
```

dif is the close array's max minus it's min toFixed(7)

[image: Normalized]

I am no mathematician but I think I am 'sort of close' with the log part, though I only see a visual difference when I apply a log function **during** normalization. This messes up the normalization obviously and It also produces Infinity or -Infinity and very unnecessarily large numbers

[image: Out of view]

Notice that the chart is now no longer manageable in pixels as it is not sitting on the canvas properly, so to see what I have done I add 150 to all the y points to bring it into view

[image: Pushed into view]

So When I do this I am disrupting/changeing things on the same line by applying a logarithmic function (I know this part is wrong)

```
function logWithBase(n,b){return Math.log(n)/Math.log(b);}
```

changing the line like so:

```
normalized[i] = logWithBase( ( close[i] - min ) / dif , 10 ) * 100;
```

Here is a small part of the data before and after I attempt to make it logarithmic:

Before:

```
0: "0.00168927"
1: "0.00168742"
2: "0.0016818"
3: "0.00168124"
4: "0.00168067"
5: "0.0016805"
6: "0.00168657"
7: "0.00168362"
8: "0.00166886"
9: "0.00165052"    // < why does 0.00165 cause -Infinity
10: "0.0016647"
11: "0.00166251"
12: "0.00166664"
13: "0.00167196"
14: "0.00167084"
15: "0.00167667"
```

Same set after:

```
0: 38.93017025063121
1: 36.805636182304255
2: 29.629674005179268
3: 28.845120702345767
4: 28.03173121401521
5: 27.786162417624155
6: 35.79352647194307
7: 32.08579894397015
8: 6.4429326997987175
9: -Infinity             // < WOW!!
10: -4.729377348896662
11: -12.015082123716525
12: 0.8395033133056131
13: 13.225477668471285
14: 10.8953699275865
15: 21.850168886727374
```

---

**Maybe a related clue here**

If I get the difference between min and max / 2 (I'll probably get a bad mark for this) and use it as my base (before I do the simple normalization) I see the chart upside down...

```
var logclose = [];

var base = ( Math.max.apply(this,close) - Math.min.apply(this,close) ) / 2;

for( var i = close.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){

    logclose[i] = logWithBase( close[i] , base );

    }

close=logclose;
```

[image: Upside down]

Conclusion; I think the last example says that the base should be somehow related to the arrays number range as it does have an effect.

how do I tame the logarithm to not be ridiculously large numbers then normalize it to fit the canvas area?

> Please do not recommend I use a library (I prefer vanilla JavaScript where it can be used, plus, I would very much like to grasp this proccess)

**Edit, here is the code:**

```
var close=[data]; // for example data see this question (line: 19) as the full data will not fit here (over 10000 entries)

//###

var max=Math.max.apply(this,close);
var min=Math.min.apply(this,close);
var dif=(max-min).toFixed(7);

var normalclose=[];
var logAttemptClose=[];

function logWithBase(n,b){return Math.log(n)/Math.log(b);}

for(var i=close.length-1;i>=0;i--){

    normalclose[i]=((close[i]-min)/dif)*100;

    logAttemptClose[i]=logWithBase( ( close[i] - min ) / dif , 10 ) * 100; // <-- here bad code
    }

//drawing to canvas
var top=100;
var x=1000-100;
var pen=[];

pen[0]=document.getElementById("chart");
pen[0]=pen[0].getContext("2d");
pen[0].clearRect(0,0,1000,300);
pen[0].beginPath();
pen[0].moveTo(x,normalclose[normalclose.length-1]+top);

for(var i=close.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    x=x-(2);
    pen[0].lineTo(x,normalclose[i]+top);
    }

pen[0].strokeStyle='#000000';
pen[0].stroke();
```

Comment: If you are going to down vote, please be constructive/professional about it and give an explanation

Comment: That's hard to help you without the full code. But you should check every step to verify if you have any `undefined`/`NaN`/`null` value somewhere.

Comment: The question gives a lot of information, shows an honest effort and is well asked, I find it a bit harsh to downvote. (+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Got Ya!!**

Ok, this is not the best fix but it works! If anyone can do this better please post..

Add this to line 2 of the above code (where the comment '###' is):

```
var Lmax=Math.max.apply(this,close);
var Lmin=Math.min.apply(this,close);
var Ldif=(Lmax-Lmin);
var Logar=[];
var infinity=[];
for(var i=close.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    Logar[i]=Math.log((close[i]-Lmin)/Ldif);
    if(Logar[i]===-Infinity){infinity.push(i);}
    }
close=Logar;
```

Now we have the array at logarithmic scale but there is always ALWAYS -Infinity in there somewhere so we remove it. On the next line write...

```
for(var i=0;i<=infinity.length-1;i++){close.splice(infinity[i],1);
```

Then we can continue with the code moving on to simple normalization and we have a nice new log chart:

[image: Hacked]

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are normalising the data in linear space (by subtracting the minimum) and *then* converting to logarithmic space.

Inevitable one of your values becomes zero, hence `log(0) == -Infinity`.

Instead, take the logarithm first on unnormalised data, and *then* determine the ranges of your Y axis for plotting.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/r71s8cex/

Comment: logAttemptClose[i]=logWithBase( ( close[i] - min ) / dif , 10 ) * 100;

would then be?

logAttemptClose[i]=logWithBase( close[i] / dif , 10 ) * 100;

Comment: no - you need to move the whole "min" / "max" stuff until _after_ the log operation.